# Is it possible to use an image for ipywidget button

Tags: image, button, ipywidgets

According to doc: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Button, it does not seem like you can use an image as the Description of a iPyWidget button. I.e., i don't want to use any text, but an icon. That icon attribute doesn't seem to be related to this.

```
widgets.Button(
    description='Click me',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='check' # (FontAwesome names without the `fa-` prefix)
)
```

Anyone has a way to do this?

Comment: I believe only Font Awesome 4.7.0 icons are supported at the moment.

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Comment: I found a good enough workaround, I just use unicode for the icon I want.

Answer (score 0):

Using unicode to display an icon. This may good enough depend on your own requirement.